# FormGroup form.reset() affecting mat-error

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use mat-error inside my form with FormGroup.I have an auction site and when I place a bid, I have it doing a `this.form.reset()` to clear the field after submission, but my mat-error goes off when I clear the field. How can I clear the form field and not cause the mat-error to turn on?

```
 <div id="bidding">
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formFields">
      <mat-label id="placeholder">Enter Bid</mat-label>
      <input id='listing-{{auction.id}}' matInput name="bidInput" type="text" required
         formControlName="bidInput" pattern="^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,3}(,\d{3})*)|0)?\.\d{2}$" />
      <mat-error>Dollar Format 00.00 or 0.00</mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
   <button id="auctionButton" mat-raised-button type="submit"
      (click)="confirmBid(auction.currentBid, auction.id)">Submit
   Bid</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try to add an `ngIf` to your `mat-error` to only show when the `FormName.get('bidInput').hasError('pattern')"` and see what happens.

Comment: a mat-error, by defect is showed if the control is invalid and touched. reset() mark the control as untouched. This is the reason your "error" disapear. solution? after reset, mark as touched

Comment: @Kardon63 I tried that and it does remove the mat-error message, but the mat-form-field is still coloring the border red as if there is an error. They are by default black. How can I get the mat-form-field to play nicely too?

Comment: @Eliseo I tried this        ```this.form.reset(); this.form.markAsTouched();``` but it doesn't make any difference. The error comes up and the mat-form-field becomes highlighted red as if there is an error.

Comment: i think because the filed is `required` then you need to add another  `<mat-error *ngIf="FormName.get('bidInput').hasError('required')">This Filed is required</mat-error>` under your first `mat-error`, please try it and inform me with the result

Comment: ```This Filed is required``` appears when I submit a bid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [resetForm()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective#resetform). for more details go to [Github Issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4190).

---

**First way**

```
<!-- xxxxxx.controller.html -->

<form [formGroup]="form"> .... </form>
```

```
// xxxxxx.controller.ts

@ViewChild(FormGroupDirective) form: FormGroupDirective;

resetForm() {
  this.form.resetForm();
}
```

---

**Second way**

```
<!-- xxxxxx.controller.html -->

<form [formGroup]="form"> 
  ....
  
  <button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="form.reset()">
    reset
  </button>
</form>
```

---

**Third way**

```
<!-- xxxxxx.controller.html -->

<form [formGroup]="form"> 
  ....
  
  <button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="resetForm(form)">
    reset
  </button>
</form>
```

```
// xxxxxx.controller.ts

resetForm(form: FormGroup) {
    form.reset();
    Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {
      form.get(key).setErrors(null) ;
    });
}
```

Comment: The third way worked well for me. Thanks! I'll release the bounty to you tomorrow when it unlocks. It won't let me atm.